# How to make a graduation for displaying the time of the events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

how would like to know how to do something like this gantt ?

[image]

I tried many thing since few hours but i cant find the right solution.
let me explain, i have many progressBar created with ReactJs, and i try to put on the top of my timeline a spacing with minutes to locate the progress of my events which are on my progressBar, so i wanted to created something like on this picture.

```js
function myFunction() {
    $('div').append('<br />' + new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes());
}

var i = setInterval(function() { myFunction(); }, 5000);

$('a').click(function() {
    clearInterval(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Stop!</a>
<div></div>
```

i tried to make this code to generate a spacing of time but that cant work because if i refress the page, all the dates Are going to disappear.

someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(i);
});
```